# What I have to do to start the app from background with Login.class or MainActivity? - ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, authentication, background, launch

im creating an app in Android Studio in which there are users and you need to Log in. When I launch the app it's all fine but the the problem is when I started the app from the background in my smartphone. THE APP STARTS WITH **DISPATCH ACTIVITY**, (the **launcher activity**), which is all in blank, so it's so ugly and unconfortable. I think it should start with **Login.class** or **MainAcitivty.class**, of course, it depends if the user is logged in or not.

What im doing wrong? How can i fix it? THANKS IN ADVANCE.

```
public class DispatchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Check if there is current user info
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // Start an intent for the logged in activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

    } else {
        // Start and intent for the logged out activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "started the app from the background" do you mean starting it from a service or a broadcast receiver? The reason why you DispatchActivity is blank is because you haven't called setContentView() . Moreover, you must not use an activity just to launch other activities. Use a broadcast receiver or a service for that

Comment: I mean, when you close an app from your smartphone, its in background, like "still open". Yeah, i know that about setContentVIew. the point is that i dont want to show anything in DIspatchActivity. i just want DispatchActivity to decide of showing MainActivity or Login activity

Comment: What would u use to launch other activities?

Comment: Do you want to lunch the activities if the user is user is logged in or not ?Then create a single activity with two diffent UIs, one for when the user is logged in and one for when his not. You can use a two different fragments for that. Creating an activity just to lunch another activity is a bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preferences for this. When user logged in then you can save user id in preference , when app comes at background open Splash or Login or MainActivity but you need to check once if preference exist then navigate to MainActivity otherwise Login screen . Hope it helps . Like this :

```
if(Utils.getuserid(c).equals("")){
        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, LoginActivity.class));

    }else{

    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));

    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks because your quick answer, but i dont get it, what do u mean with "splash activity"? Could you be more specific about that Preferences?

Comment: Hi  ferrvn, 
Yes after first login you can use preference for saving data . I am sharing you the link that demonstrate how we save and get the data from preferences. Please refer and if you have any query you can ask me any time Bro. 

http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146